# Binarization methods, middle-threshold binarisation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, image

I'm trying to binarise a picture, firstly of course having it prepared(grayscaling)
My method is to find the maximum and minimum values of grayscale, then find the middle value(which is my threshold) and then, iterating over all the pixels I compare the current one with a threshold and if the grayscale is larger than the threshold, I put 0 in a matrix, or for the others I put 1.
But now I'm facing the problem. In common I'm binarising images with white background, so my algorithm is further based on this feature. But when I meet an image with black background everything collapses, but I still can see the number clearly(now 0's and 1's switch places)
How can i solve this problem, make my program more common?
Maybe I'd better look for another ways of binarization/

P.S. I looked for an understandable explanation of Otsu threshold method, but it seems either I'm not prepared for this way of difficulty or I find very complicated explanations every time, but I can't write it in C. If anyone could hrlp here, it'd be wonderful.

Sorry for not answering the questions, just didn't see them
Firstly - the code

```
for (int y=1;y<Source->Picture->Height;y++)
    for (int x=1;x<Source->Picture->Width;x++)
    {
        unsigned green = GetGValue(Source->Canvas->Pixels[x][y]);
        unsigned red = GetRValue(Source->Canvas->Pixels[x][y]);
        unsigned blue = GetBValue(Source->Canvas->Pixels[x][y]);
        threshold = (0.2125*red+0.7154*green+0.0721*blue);
        if (min>threshold)
            min=threshold;
        if (max<threshold)
            max = threshold;
    }
    middle = (max+min)/2;
```

Then iterating through the image

```
        if (threshold<middle)
        {
            picture[x][y]=1;
            fprintf( fo,"1");
        } else {
            picture[x][y]=0;
            fprintf( fo,"0");
        }
    }
    fprintf( fo,"\n");
}
fclose(fo);
```

So I get a file, something like this

> 000000000
>   000001000
>   000001000
>   000011000
>   000101000
>   000001000
>   000001000
>   000001000
>   000000000

Here you can see an example of one. [image]

Then I can interpolate it, or do something else (recognize), depending on zero's and one's.
But if I switch the colors, the numbers won't be the same. So the recognition will not work. I wonder if there's an algoritm that can help me out.

Comment: Why does it "collapse"?  Sounds like it should work fine for black backgrounds.

Comment: Can you point us to a couple of sample pictures, one white background and one black background?

Comment: I've read the problem a few times, I really cannot figure out what you're asking of us.  Can you re-word the question to clarify?

Comment: @Mooing Duck That's okay, everything's clearly done. You've helped a lot with the explamation of Otsu's treshold, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of Otsu's method, but I understand some of the wikipedia page so I'll try to simplify that.

```
1 Count how many pixels are at each level of darkness.
2 "Guess" a threshold.
3 Calculate the variance of the counts of darkness less than the threshold
4 Calculate the variance of the counts of darkness greater than the threshold
5 If the variance of the darker side is greater, guess a darker threshold, 
  else guess a higher threshold.
  Do this like a binary search so that it ends.
6 Turn all pixels darker than threshold black, the rest white.
```

Otsu's method is actually "maximizing inter-class variance", but I don't understand that part of the math.

The concept of variance, is "how far apart are the values from each other."  A low variance means everything is similar.  A high variance means the values are far apart.  The variance of a rainbow is very high, lots of colors.  The variance of the background of stackoverflow is 0, since it's all perfectly white, with no other colors.  Variance is calculated more or less like this

```
double variance(unsigned int* counts, int size, int threshold, bool above) {
    //this is a quick trick to turn the "upper" into lower, save myself code
    if (above) return variance(counts, size-threshold, size-threshold, false);
    //first we calculate the average value
    unsigned long long atotal=0;
    unsigned long long acount=0;
    for(int i=0; i<threshold; ++i) {
        atotal += counts[i]*i //number of px times value
        acount += counts[i];
    }
    //finish calculating average
    double average = double(atotal)/count;
    //next we calculate the variance
    double vtotal=0;
    for(int i=0; i<threshold; ++i) {
        //to do so we get each values's difference from the average
        double t = std::abs(i-average);
        //and square it (I hate mathmaticians)
        vtotal += counts[i]*t*t;
    }
    //and return the average of those squared values.
    return vtotal/count;
}
```

Comment: Let's see, what I understood.
At first, I'm just doing a histogram. It may be a matrix with one index showing the greyscale values and the other - numbers of them.
Then I'm just picking some value.
Then I'm counting how many values of darker/higher pixels.
Then I'm deciding whether to lower or higher the first treshold value.
The next thing I do not understand, so when should I end my treshold choice?
The last thing is clear to me as well

Comment: @user1131662: I updated the answer with a variance function.  If the guess is too dark, then the variance of the lighter pixels will be high, if the guess is too light, the variance of the darker pixels will be high.  You have to do a binary search for the threshold where the two variances are as close as possible.

Comment: @user1131662: I commented the variance function

Comment: I'm very grateful for your efforts, but it seems, that I'm even more stupid. I have a problem understanding small pieces of code. But again, thank you, now that I have an algoritm, it's easier to understand (rather than just math functions)

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this problem with another approach:

- Compute the cumulative histogram of greyscaled values of the image.
- Use as threshold the pixel value in which this cumulative
  reaches half of the total pixels of the image.

The algorithm would go as follows:

```
  int bin [256];
  foreach pixel in image
       bin[pixelvalue]++;  
  endfor  // this computes the histogram of the image

  int thresholdCount = ImageWidth * ImageSize / 2;
  int count = 0;
  for int i = 0 to 255
    count = count + bin[i];
    if( count > thresholdCount)
         threshold = i;
         break; // we are done
    endif
  endfor
```

This algorithm does not compute the cumulative histogram itself but rather uses the image histogram to do what I said earlier.

Comment: Firstly I iterate through all the pixels and summarize their greyscaled values. S = g1+g2+g3
Secondly I divide this s value by half the number of all pixels in an image. Is it right?

Comment: No, that will give you double the average value, which might not even be a valid value.  Though I do not understand this answer either.

Comment: @user1131662, what you're describing is (almost) the mean value, what gusbro is suggesting is the median value. The difference will depend on the distribution of values in your image.

Comment: Well, then if anyone else could help here, it'd be great.

Comment: @MooingDuck, this answer picks a threshold which attempts to make the result half white and half black. Given that the question states a white background I'd question whether this solution is appropriate.

Comment: @Mark Ransom so, you mean the gusbro's method will work correctly? Fine, thanks, I'll try it out as soon as possible, hope nothing else collapses.

Comment: Check [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Cumulative_histogram) to see what is a cumulative histogram and also check the updated answer.

Comment: This algorithm is fast and easy!  Nice!  Just notice that it has problems if the "background" is a large portion of the pixels.

Comment: FWIW, this solution is equivalent to using the median as threshold.

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm works properly for white backgrounds but fails for black backgrounds, you simply need to detect when you have a black background and invert the values. If you assume the background value will be more common, you can simply count the number of 1s and 0s in the result; if the 0s are greater, invert the result.

Comment: Well, the white background is more common, but of course I need all exceptions to work properly. The most frustrating is that everything is very dependable. I hope I'll get away just with this inverting, but just in case it won't work I decided to ask

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using mean of min and max, you should use median of all points as threshold. In general kth percentile (k = what percentage of points you want as black) is more appropriate.

Another solution is to cluster the data into two clusters.

Comment: This just trades one problem for another - instead of figuring out the appropriate threshold you're trying to figure out the appropriate percentile. Tthat might simplify the problem or it might not - we don't know enough about this problem yet.

Comment: @MarkRansom Threshold you are using is a bit arbitrary (a noisy max or min will ruin the whole picture). In my approach you set percentile to how many black pixels you want to see in the picture, which is quite intuitive. Another solution is to cluster the data into two clusters.